# Getting 401 unauthenticated error in WP Rest API revisions

Tags: rest-api, revisions, previews

I'm trying to fetch preview data through WP Rest API using a url such as `/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/1140/revisions/1653`.

An extra header is also included: `'X-WP-Nonce': <nonce>` - nonce comes from WP.

Why am I getting 401 unauth error? Thanks

```
{ code: 'rest_cannot_read',
2020-07-21T11:45:35.930292+00:00 app[web.1]:   message: 'Sorry, you are not allowed to view revisions of this post.',
2020-07-21T11:45:35.930293+00:00 app[web.1]:   data: { status: 401 } }
```

Comment: Seems like the user that Wordpress thinks you are when accessing the API doesn't have permission for that resource. Have you looked into how you login  for the API? E.g. some content here https://www.cloudways.com/blog/setup-basic-authentication-in-wordpress-rest-api/

Comment: You're right! The API token was kind of expired (deleted). Did not even even need nonce. Thanks!

Comment: @haxpanel can you post that as an answer in case someone else has this issue? I can't upvote your answer and give you rep if it's just a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to generate and use an API token.

1. in WP admin, go to user and generate the key
2. take that key and glue it with the username it is generated with in this format: `username:key`
3. base64 encode that string
4. put that base64 value into the header: `'Authorization': 'Basic <base64 token here>'`

In my case, the key was deleted.